# Laravel: hasMany relationship + where condition fails

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I have a `Customer` Eloquent model. `Customer` can have multiple `WishLists` where he / she can add some products. Typical ecommerce functionality.

The point is that `Customer` can belong to many `Users` models.

This was easy:

```
public function users()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(User::class, 'users_sync_customers', 'customer_uuid', 'user_id')
        ->withTimestamps()
        ->orderBy('last_name', 'asc');
}
```

So I can get all `Customers` assigned for logged in user by

`auth()->user()->customers`

As I mentioned, `Customer` can have multiple `Wishlists`:

```
public function wishLists()
{
    return $this
        ->hasMany(WishList::class, 'customer_uuid', 'uuid')
        ->where('user_id', '=', auth()->user()->id); // <----- this will fail when I log out
}
```

but `WishList` is scoped to both Customer UUID **and** User ID.

[image]

Above relationship works but only when I'm logged in obviously.

As soon as I log out the `auth()->user()->is` is `NULL` and I get:

> ErrorException {#1483   #message: "Trying to get property 'id' of
>   non-object"

Question: How can I reference in `wishLists()` the `user_id` value?

`WishList` model has this:

```
public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'user_id', 'id');
}
```

So can I use something like `$this->user->id`?

edit:

Nope, this also doesn't work.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

you must check that the user is logged in?

```
Auth::check() ? Auth::user()->id : null
```